# how to parse JSON with single and double quotes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, parsing

I am Having an issue where if a name comes in with a `'` or `"` my JSON parsing fails. I want to know how i can avoid this.

This is my current code:

```
def create

puts params

#@contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
#@contact.user = current_user

contactsParam = params[:contacts]

if contactsParam

  # contactsParam.each do |contact|
  # end

  contactValues = contactsParam.map { |c| 

    puts "dulce!!! : " + c.to_s

    json = JSON.parse(c)
    result = "('#{json['name']}', '#{json['phone_number']}', '#{json['detail']}', '#{json['image_url']}', '#{json['email']}', '#{json['address']}', '#{json['city']}', '#{json['state']}', '#{json['zipcode']}', '#{json['country']}', #{current_user.id}, now(), now())" 
    result
  }.join(",")

  if contactValues.length > 0
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO contacts (name, phone_number, detail, image_url, email, address, city, state, zipcode, country, user_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{contactValues}")
  end
end
```

here is an example of a JSON String that fails (i added a bunch of random characters to test).

```
   {"name":"Aaacontacttest'/'@"-jgg&$;$/&/@.'sheh","phone_number":",7*#;878545848487849648","detail":"","image_url":"","email":"test@test.com","address":"-/:;()$@""":$;$:$$/!:!/!,!6677bhgv
2017-07-25T20:08:54.614283+00:00 app[web.1]: Hsbsbsbb7788$!","city":"Hehshdbdb","state":"HSSHHSHS$&:$:$","zipcode":"3319)","country":"United States"}
```

Comment: Remove all the irrelevant fluff from the code and show actual input.

Comment: Do you really need to interpolate those values for `result`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma do you know of a better way i could do it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i added a test input i am using to make sure that no special characters would make the parsing fail

Comment: @RickS: that's obviously not a valid json. What is it that you want to do here?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i want to allow characters like ' and " go through, i know you can replace ' with \' and it will allow it to parse the JSON but i don't know how i can achieve that in ruby

Comment: @RickS: ruby has a variety of string replacement methods. `gsub` is one of them, check it out.

Comment: @RickS The problem with your input is that you want to escape the "inner" quotes, but not the "outer" ones. How can you determine which is which is non-trivial, to say the least.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're right i guess i am going to have to do this on my swift application before it gets sent

Answer (score 2):

1.

Let's first correct the JSON Object which you gave:

```
  {
    "name":"Aaacontacttest'/'@"-jgg&$;$/&/@.'sheh",
    "phone_number":",7*#;878545848487849648",
    "detail":"",
    "image_url":"",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "address":"-/:;()$@""":$;$:$$/!:!/!,!6677bhgv2017-07-25T20:08:54.614283+00:00 app[web.1]: Hsbsbsbb7788$!",
    "city":"Hehshdbdb",
    "state":"HSSHHSHS$&:$:$",
    "zipcode":"3319)",
    "country":"United States"
}
```

The problem with this JSON object is, it is not closed properly. If you wanted to use quotes in your object then please use Backslash to omit to close the value of the object.

Let's convert the above **invalid JSON Object to valid JSON object** first, such ruby avoid syntax error:

```
 {
    "name":"Aaacontacttest'/'@\"-jgg&$;$/&/@.'sheh",
    "phone_number":",7*#;878545848487849648",
    "detail":"",
    "image_url":"",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "address":"-/:;()$@\"\"\":$;$:$$/!:!/!,!6677bhgv2017-07-25T20:08:54.614283+00:00 app[web.1]: Hsbsbsbb7788$!",
    "city":"Hehshdbdb",
    "state":"HSSHHSHS$&:$:$",
    "zipcode":"3319)",
    "country":"United States"
}
```

What we did over here:
Initial Hash object with the "name" as the key has a value:

"name":**"Aaacontacttest'/'@"**-jgg&$;$/&/@.'sheh"

Area with bold depicting that you have closed the value with quotes where rest of the Italic character is marked as invalid.

Types of errors which ruby would be raised either "syntax error" or unexpected 'any char', expecting end-of-input

We have introduced backslash in the value to ensure proper closing of the value.

"name":**"Aaacontacttest'/'@\"**-jgg&$;$/&/@.'sheh"

**So where ever you have used quotes in your value please omit them using backslash.**

2. **The object which you gave is the normal hash object not a JSON object in case of ruby, as Ruby JSON parser expects the argument to be a string and can’t convert objects like a hash or array.**

If you do **JSON.generate(hash)** you will get the JSON object:

Note: hash if the corrected hashobject.

Adding JSON object over here.

"{\"name\":\"Aaacontacttest'/'@\\"-jgg&$;$/&/@.'sheh\",\"phone_number\":\",7*#;878545848487849648\",\"detail\":\"\",\"image_url\":\"\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"address\":\"-/:;()$@\\"\\"\\":$;$:$$/!:!/!,!6677bhgv2017-07-25T20:08:54.614283+00:00 app[web.1]: Hsbsbsbb7788$!\",\"city\":\"Hehshdbdb\",\"state\":\"HSSHHSHS$&:$:$\",\"zipcode\":\"3319)\",\"country\":\"United States\"}"

If you do **JSON.parse(HashObject not JSONobject)** the ruby would throw an error:

TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String

Summary:

1. Correct your hashObject.
2. Convert you hashObject into the valid JSON object for ruby. If you wanted to generate JSON use JSON.generate(hash) method.